# Setting the root-disk constraint in a juju application to use ssd instead of magnetic on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, storage, juju

When you deploy a Kubernetes cluster with juju on AWS the default root disk of all the master and worker nodes is a 'magnetic' storage. I want to set this to use ssd (gp2) instead.

I cannot find any way to do this per application (e.g. kubernetes-worker)
`juju get-constrains kubernetes-worker` is now => `cores=2 mem=4096M root-disk=51200M`.

Spinning up new machines always gives me magnetic root disks. https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.5/en/reference-constraints shows all constraints and no mention of 'volume type' or other.

There is a way to make new storage classes and to attach them to machines/units after deploy, but I would like to add it as default per application when adding new units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this myself and I wasn't able to create an SSD EBS root volume either. I tried this:

```
$ juju storage-pools
$ juju model-config storage-default-block-source=ebs-ssd
$ juju deploy canonical-kubernetes --storage data=ebs-ssd,10G,1
```

It looks like the charms: [kubernetes worker](https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/~containers/kubernetes-worker/archive/metadata.yaml), and [kubernetes master](https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/~containers/kubernetes-master/archive/metadata.yaml)  don't have support for a storage label. But you can see that [etcd](https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/etcd/archive/metadata.yaml) does have support. So, it's likely one doesn't work with the other, there are also related juju [open issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1691694) to support storage bindings in bundles.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx for the answer, i tried changing the model-config and then adding a unit to an existing application. This did not change the root-disk from (standard-magnetic) to gp2 ssd.. so i would most likely have to redeploy the whole kubernetes cluster to get the storage attached. Also I dont need persistent storage but only ssd to the root-disks (ephemeral storage)